# How do I pixelate a scene with SceneKit and Metal, in Swift?

Tags: shaders, rendering, ios, swift, scenekit

I managed to get pixelation working by using the OpenGLES2 rendering API, and a CIFilter. But it was way too slow, so I want to use the Metal API and just have a very simple filter that pixelates everything in the scene.

Would really appreciate some help, maybe just explaining how to set up SceneKit to use a Metal shader. Is there something I can just drop in with a few lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be quite as easy as you'd like, that said you should be able to copy/paste the code below to get something going.

There might be a better way to approach this, but as I see it you'll need 2 render passes. The first to render the scene to a low resolution to introduce pixelation, and a second to resample the low resolution render to the resolution of the screen. [`SCNTechnique`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNTechnique_Class/) is how multi-pass rendering is supported in SceneKit.

The following xml defines the rendering passes for this pixelate technique, add a plist file to you project (`pixelate.plist`) and paste this in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>passes</key>
        <dict>

            <key>pixelate_scene</key>
            <dict>
                <key>draw</key>
                <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
                <key>inputs</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>outputs</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>color</key>
                    <string>color_scene</string>
                </dict>
                <key>colorStates</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>clear</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>clearColor</key>
                    <string>sceneBackground</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>

            <key>resample_pixelation</key>
            <dict>
                <key>draw</key>
                <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
                <key>program</key>
                <string>doesntexist</string>
                <key>metalVertexShader</key>
                <string>pixelate_pass_through_vertex</string>
                <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
                <string>pixelate_pass_through_fragment</string>
                <key>inputs</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>colorSampler</key>
                    <string>color_scene</string>
                </dict>
                <key>outputs</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>color</key>
                    <string>COLOR</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>


        </dict>
        <key>sequence</key>
        <array>
            <string>pixelate_scene</string>
            <string>resample_pixelation</string>
        </array>
        <key>targets</key>
        <dict>
            <key>color_scene</key>
            <dict>
                <key>type</key>
                <string>color</string>
                <key>size</key>
                <string>75x75</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>symbols</key>
        <dict></dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

If you'd like to understand more about what's going on in this block of XML refer to the Apple docs, I'll only cover the specifics here. The `sequence` element defines the order of our two render passes; `pixelate_scene` and `resample_pixelation`. The definition of each pass is defined in the `passes` element.

With the `DRAW_SCENE` draw instruction and not setting any shaders to the `pixelate_scene` we tell SceneKit to simply render the scene to the output target (a texture) using its standard shaders. The target in this case `color_scene` is a color texture with a size of 75x75px, this is defined in the `targets` element at the end of the xml file.

The `resample_pixelation` pass is a bit different, as now we want to perform a rendering pass over the texture in `color_scene`. To do this we use the `DRAW_QUAD` draw instruction, with this SceneKit builds us a fullscreen quad on which our input texture is mapped. This time we do need to define a vertex and fragment shader.

It doesn't matter what `.metal` file you include this in, only the shader names do need to match those found in the plist definition.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct custom_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
};

constexpr sampler s = sampler(coord::normalized,
                              address::repeat,
                              filter::nearest);

struct out_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex out_vertex_t pixelate_pass_through_vertex(custom_vertex_t in [[stage_in]],
                                                 constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]])
{
    out_vertex_t out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.uv = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
};

fragment half4 pixelate_pass_through_fragment(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]],
                                              texture2d<float, access::sample> colorSampler [[texture(0)]])
{
    float4 fragment_color = colorSampler.sample( s, vert.uv);
    return half4(fragment_color);
};
```

This is a simple Metal shader for our fullscreen quad. The vertex shader calculates the UV texture coordinates, and the fragment shader simply resamples the input texture (low res 75x75 texture) and writes it to the output. One thing to point out is in the sampler definition, using `filter::nearest` means that we'll get nice sharp pixels. You could also use something like `filter::linear`, but this would blur the pixels.

Lastly you'll need to apply this `SCNTechnique`.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pixelate", ofType: "plist") {
    if let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)  {
        let plistStrDict = plistDict as! [String : AnyObject]
        let pixelateTechnique = SCNTechnique(dictionary:plistStrDict)
        scnView.technique = pixelateTechnique
    }
}
```

And if all goes according to plan...

[image: SceneKit pixelation SCNTechnique, before and after]

Source code for this can be found in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lachlanhurst/SCNTechniqueTest/tree/pixelate), just make sure you check out the pixelate branch.

Comment: This is so amazing, thanks so much!!! I'm looking forward to trying it out tonight

Comment: No problem, just added a link to the source code in my GitHub repo. Good luck!

Comment: "just added a link to the source code in my GitHub repo" Remember that everything you post here is under CC-by-SA :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreVaillancourt . Code in the GitHub repo is under MIT, I'm also fine with CC-by-SA, so go with what suits best.

Comment: This is great! It should be noted, however, that for this particular effect, you can also simply include a `CIFilter` as part of the node's `filters` array to render screen-space effects using Core Image really easily. `CIPixelate` does a great job.

Comment: I've yet to experiment with what's been fixed/improved in iOS10, so this answer may indeed now be redundant...  my main problems were that CI filters didn't work with Metal and they were painfully slow when using GLSL. At the time I believed they were doing the filter on the CPU requiring a GPU->CPU->GPU round trip. If these issues have been fixed up as you seem to indicate, then yes CIFilter's will certainly make everyone's life easier!

Comment: Yep! As of iOS 10/tvOS 10, the Metal renderer can use `CIFilter`s just fine, which is great. I nagged one of the SceneKit engineers enough that he was able to get it fixed. :)